# Hierarchical Cluster Analysis on large dataset in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, large-data

I wonder what would be the best (and the fastest) way to run Hierarchical Cluster Analysis in R on a large data: 50000x3000? To get dist() for the data seems to be the endless job...

Many thanks! PM

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [bigmemory](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigmemory/index.html) and [biganalytics](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/biganalytics/index.html).